# SSL exception on local https server in python

Tags: python, ssl, https, activestate, python-server-pages

I am using windows 7 and python 2.7
I created local https server with redirect url to server as its **IP address**. I created cert file for https using openssl.
Everyting is fine but getting SSL Exception when it redirects to local https server.
Since, this server is created locally, everytime my application is launched, so we cannot buy a ssl certificate, since redirect url is system's IP address.
I used [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442473-simple-http-server-supporting-ssl-secure-communica/) for creating local server. 
So, how to avoid this SSL Exception.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use as workaround :

- Use something like dyndns (or a subdomain ?) and buy a SSL certificate
- Install your SSL certificate in your browser as Verified certificate

Comment: I want to distribute this app to others. So, IP address of other user will be their redirect address of https server. So how to buy a fixed certificate as IP is different for different user.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever is operating the server needs a valid certificate for it, matching the hostname used to visit the site.

If the application is only visited from the local machine, just call it using 127.0.0.1 instead of the external IP, without HTTPS. Since the data never leaves the machine, using HTTPS is pointless. (In this situation, you probably also want to bind the web server to 127.0.0.1 to prevent others from visiting the site).

If the application is visited from other machines on the network too, and you want to use SSL, whoever runs the application will need a certificate matching the hostname in the URL. You can't get certificates for private IPs (e.g. 192.168.1.1 or 10.2.3.4), but if it is a public IP, you might be able to get a certificate for that.

It is much more reasonable, though, to point some host name (DynDNS if your CA allows it, or a subdomain of a domain belonging to whoever runs the app) at the IP. For example, a company called Example owning example.com could use webapp.example.com, point it to their server, and get a cert for that. Whoever runs the server will need to deploy that certificate, and your app needs to be designed to accept it. **You will need one certificate per customer site.** No (secure) way around that if you want it to work on out-of-the-box browsers.

You might be able to simplify the process by providing automated workflows to request certificates, or even creating your own dyndns-like service for your customers, where they can register theirname.yourservice.com, get it pointed to the IP of their desire, and get a cert for their host from you. (This requires them to trust you a lot and is somewhat of an antipattern, but possibly the least nasty solution.) You still need to make sure that every customer has their own certificate. Most importantly, DO NOT try getting a wildcard certificate for such a domain and distributing the cert and private key together with the app. Anyone who has a copy of your app would be able to attack the "secure" connections. More importantly, once the CA finds out, your cert gets revoked, and that will prevent access to the site with a very harsh warning and no way to bypass the warning. And probably get you in trouble with the CA for violating your agreement with them to safeguard the private keys.

Another option, though, is to just generate a self-signed certificate on first startup, and output the fingerprint. **Do not use the same hardcoded certificate for all installations**, as convenient as it may be, because a private key distributed to all your customers is not private. This certificate will generate the warning you are seeing. You will now have to add this certificate or an exception for this site to the browsers used to visit the app. As long as you verify the fingerprint, this is secure - it is just more work. Depending on the browser users are using, there may be ways to easily roll out such a cert to multiple machines.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am using local https server as, it is used for authentication of user with gmail. when user log in to gmail account, gmail sends success code and access token to this local https server. I want to distribute this app to others. So, IP address of other user will be their redirect address of https server. So how to buy a fixed certificate as IP is different for different user.

Comment: First, try using 127.0.0.1 as a redirect target. It won't solve your problem but is cleaner and (if it works) probably more reliable. The easiest approach - especially if it's supposed to work cross-browser - would probably be manually confirming the warning and adding a permanent exception - if you manage to move it to 127.0.0.1, there is little risk in that. If you want HTTPS without a warning, you need a valid certificate, and you need a separate one for each user. You might be able to generate one and install it in the browser on the fly during installation, but that will be a lot of work.